# Defining the domain of positive real numbers

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I am trying to solve an equation by assuming that all the variables are real and strictly positive. I can use the keyword `Reals` for the argument `dom` in the Solve function `Solve[expr,vars,dom]`. Is there an equivalent for strictly positive `Reals`? Something like `PosReals`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding here.  The third "dom" argument is not simply a set over which we solve the equation.  There are only a few choices that can be used for the domain argument, and they have very specific effects on how `Solve` works.  An example from the documentation:

> If dom is Reals, or a subset such as Integers or Rationals, then all constants and function values are also restricted to be real.

So you can't use e.g.

```
Solve[x^2 == 1, x, Interval[{0, Infinity}]]
```

The proper way to do this, as @belisarius said, is to append the constraint to the system of equations:

```
Solve[x^2 == 1 && x > 0, x]
```

In version 10 we can also do

```
Solve[x^2 == 1 && x ∈ Interval[{0, Infinity}], x]
```

or even

```
Solve[x^2 == 1, x ∈ Interval[{0, Infinity}]]
```

Comment: That totally makes sense now +1. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

New in Mathematica 12 is [`PositiveReals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositiveReals) (and others like [`NonNegativeIntegers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonNegativeIntegers), etc):

```
Solve[x^2 == 1, x, PositiveReals]
```

> {{x -> 1}}

Answer (score 4):

```
{Solve [ x^2 == 1, {x}], Solve [ x^2 == 1 && x > 0, {x}]}
(* {{{x -> -1}, {x -> 1}}, {{x -> 1}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with multiple variables, I suggest you to use `Assumptions` under function `Refine`, like below

```
Refine[Reduce[{52*n^2 + 19*n*nb - 42*n*nf > 0, 52*n^2 - 61*n*nb - 42*n*nf > 0}, {n, nb, nf}], Assumptions -> n > 0 && nb > 0 && nf > 0]
```

This feature can be used for most type operations. For reference, please see [Assumptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html).