# Restricting Solve to positive reals

Tags: equation-solving

I want to restrict the solutions to Solve to the positive reals.
This is my code:

```
bet = 0.001; 
fc1 = (2/8)^2;
fc2 = ((3)/8)^2;   
N1p = N1*(1 - m) + N2*m;
N2p = N2*(1 - m) + N1*m;
b1 = 1 - bet*N1p - fc1;
b2 = 1 - bet*N2p - fc2;

Solve[{N1 == N1p*b1*2, N2 == N2p*b2*2 && N1>0 && 
N2> 0}, {N1, N2}]
```

I get the error

> Solve::eqf: N2>0 is not a well-formed equation. >>.

Even when I try something much simpler like:

```
Solve[x^2 == 1 && x > 0, x]
```

which I got from  [1]: [Defining the domain of positive real numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78348/defining-the-domain-of-positive-real-numbers), I get the following error message:

> Solve::eqf: x>0 is not a well-formed equation. >>

I am not sure what is going on. I am using version 7.0. Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Hi! I tried your simple case in Mathematica 8 and Mathematica 10, and it worked in both cases. I also tried the complicated case in Mathematica 10, and it does not seem to complain (given that you rationalize the variable bet). The result is a conditional expression for values of m though, since you have not specified any assumptions for m.

Comment: Quit kernel, try again?

Comment: I retried the simple example and still got the same error.. Is it version 7.0 then? Perhaps it is time for an upgrade..

Answer (score 1):

I work with mathematica 11.1
You do have to declare the domain of Solve[] as being Reals (v11.1) or PositiveReals(v12). Otherwise Solve[] results in a empty solution.

```
Solve[{N1 == N1p*b1*2, N2 == N2p*b2*2 && N1>0 && N2> 0}, {N1, N2}, Reals]
```

In Mathematica 12 you can even declare a domain as PositiveReals appearantly. N1>0 && N2> 0}, {N1, N2}, Reals] works just as well.

See [Defining the domain of positive real numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78348/defining-the-domain-of-positive-real-numbers) It is renewed following the arrival of version 12.

it's like [andy269](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27185/andy269) says without "m" being defined you get a lengthy conditional expression on "m" with goes on for nearly 300 lines and starts like this;

> ```
>  > {{N1 -> ConditionalExpression[
>  >Root[1.88672*10^10 m - 1.30514*10^11 m^2 + 2.40049*10^11 m^3 - 
>  > 1.63965*10^11 m^4 + (2.45*10^7 - 2.86375*10^8 m + 
>  >   1.16991*10^9 m^2 - 1.89913*10^9 m^3 + 
>  >     1.14563*10^9 m^4) #1 + (-112000. + 1.004*10^6 m - 
>  >     3.336*10^6 m^2 + 4.88*10^6 m^3 - 
>  >     2.656*10^6 m^4) #1^2 + (128. - 1024. m + 3072. m^2 - 
>  >     4096. m^3 + 2048. m^4) #1^3 &, 1], m > 11.4344], 
>  >N2 -> ConditionalExpression[
>  >1/(-1. + m)^2 0.0625 (2875. - 6875. m - 
>  >   16. m Root[ ect.. ect
> ```

You do get a warning in mathematica 11.1.

> ```
> > Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact
> > coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact
> > system and numericizing the result.
> ```

I'm not sure what the message means in Mathematica 11.1 and to which coefficients it refers to.

I suppose Solve[] in mathematica 7 was not ready to deal with inexact coefficients and/or variables that are not defined in the independent variable part of the equation (I really have no idea; version 7 is from 2008).

On assigning a value to 'm' say 1/2 or 2
You will get respectively;

> ```
>  > m=1/2 {{N1 -> 429.565, N2 -> 367.31}}
>  > m=2   {{N1 -> 403.528, N2 -> 369.127}}
> ```

If that's any help? It works pretty well as long as you define the domain in Solve[]. I have no clue what the calculation is all about. Possibly a binomial chance calculation? I answered this question because it helped me getting an answer to my domain problems concerning Solve[].